# Wcf Restful service post username with parameter

Tags: c#, wcf, http-post, restful-authentication, wcf-rest

I'm developer **C# .Net**
I Now programming a **Wcf restful service** for communication **mobile** with my server. But a problem in send **json request** using **post method** with parameter. After **send request** from **client**, server display error: 
**400 Bad Request**...

My **service contract**:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "login", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
[OperationContract]
string login(string username, string password);
```

And implement service:

```
public string login(string username, string password)
{
   string str = String.Empty;
   if (username == "admin" && password == "admin")
       str = "Success";
   else
       str = "Invalid";
   return str;
}
```

**Edit:**

**My host is:**

```
public void Start()
        {
            Stop();

            //string strAdrHTTP = "http://localhost:" + HttpPort + "/WcfMobileService";
            string strAdrHTTP = "http://192.168.1.190:" + HttpPort + "/WcfMobileService";
            Uri[] adrbase = { new Uri(strAdrHTTP) };

            m_svcHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TWcfMobileService), adrbase);
            WebServiceHost webServiceHost =
                new WebServiceHost(typeof(TWcfMobileService), adrbase);


            ServiceMetadataBehavior mBehave = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
            m_svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(mBehave);

            mBehave.HttpsGetEnabled = true;
            mBehave.HttpGetEnabled = true;

            WebHttpBinding webBinding = new WebHttpBinding();
            webServiceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWcfMobileServiceContract), webBinding, "rest");

            WebHttpBinding restBinding = new WebHttpBinding();

            ServiceEndpoint restSEP =
                m_svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IWcfMobileServiceContract),
                                               restBinding, "rest");
            restSEP.Behaviors.Add(new WebHttpBehavior());

            EndpointAddress myEndpointAdd = new EndpointAddress(new Uri(strAdrHTTP),
                EndpointIdentity.CreateDnsIdentity("localhost"));
            restSEP.Address = myEndpointAdd;


            m_svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IMetadataExchange),
                MetadataExchangeBindings.CreateMexHttpBinding(), "mex");

            ServiceDebugBehavior debug = new ServiceDebugBehavior();
            debug.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true;

            m_svcHost.Open();
        }
```

Comment: remove `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest`

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh Don't work

Answer (score 1):

This is an working example -

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(
        Method = "POST",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
        UriTemplate = "login")]
string login(CompositeType request);
```

Where -

```
[DataContract]
public class CompositeType
{
    [DataMember]
    public string username { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string password { get; set; }
}
```

Sample request -

```
{"request":{"username":"test","password":"test"}}
```

And it works -

[image]

Comment: thanks for answer, When i use this sample, i received  Bad Request (400)